Woocommerce products permalink based on SKU
I use this code in Wordpress (Woocommerce) to change products link:
function jpb_custom_meta_permalink( $link, $post ){
    $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sku', true );
    if( empty( $post_meta ) || !is_string( $post_meta ) )
        $post_meta = '';
    $link = str_replace( '!!custom_field_placeholder!!', $post_meta, $link );
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'jpb_custom_meta_permalink', 10, 2 );

function append_sku_string( $link, $post ) {
  $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sku', true );
      if ( 'product' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        $link = $link . $post_meta;
        return $link;
     }
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_sku_string', 1, 2 );"

This code changes products permalink to something like this:
http://example.com/product_title/sku
But what I want is:
http://example.com/product_title-sku
Any suggestion?

is the / in the post meta/custom field? Remember that post_link filter doesn't change the permalink, it filters the URL when it's displayed in HTML but the posts permalink remains the same, no rewrite rules or permalinks are changed using that filter
